# Only make it clickable if....?

Tags: android, button, click

I have an application, where you can click on the background, and it's changes from the drawables to another background, but I only want to make it clickable when the user click on a button that i call, "I want to click it".

So, how to write a code like:

```
If user click on button1 2 times, make layout clickable
else
not make layout clickable
```

So, I want to store somehow the click, and force my app to remember to it, and I also want to count the clicks.

What chapter of Android are helping me understanding this? Thanks for help, and sorry for the noobish question:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = 0;

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.i_want_to_click_it);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (++count == 2) {
            // make stuff clickable here on 2nd click
        }
        // if you also want to make things unclickable if there 
        // are more than 2 clicks, add the else{} condition
        else {
            // make stuff unclickable here
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have counter that increments on click and then just disable component when counter reach value that you want

Answer (score 1):

You can detect when user clicks a button by registering a `onClickListener` on it. Inside that callback you can count how many times it has been clicked and store that information inside a variable. If your app can change from portrait to landscape mode, dont forget to store the variable in `onSavedInstanceState` and then retrieve it in `onCreate`, because changing layout mode will destroy the activity and rebuild it which will reset your variable. I highlighted keywords to search for.